# Qt for mac os - deploy project to app file

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, .app

I have read different posts and the Qt documentation explaining command lines in shell but I cannot get through the installation of static library (and I suppose shared frameworks would be even harder) in order to produce an "app" file from my project. But I don't know why...

Would anyone be able to explain me how to get through this? Is there no "easy" way to produce a .app from Qt directly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the `qmake` to build your project, you should have in your *.pro file:

```
QT += gui
TEMPLATE = app
```

The `QT` variable will probably have more than just `gui`, but the `gui` is necessary for you to create an `app` bundle directory structure, so make sure to have it in place. The `TEMPLATE = app` is also mandatory.

After compiling with `qmake`, you should have working app bundle, which depends on your Qt installation. To make the bundle independent from your Qt installation (in other words, to make the bundle contain the Qt for its own use), use the `macdeployqt` tool from your Qt, like this:

```
macdeployqt your_app_name.app
```